# flexslider shifts when going from last item to first

Tags: drupal, themes, flexslider

OK, My flexslider shifts down when going from the last to first content . . . the image, drops down over 200px, but the other content is in place.

Also, all my images are 560px tall, but in the code, one is like 760px tall. I checked the images in the server and they are all 560px tall.

Any ideas on how to trouble shoot this?

thanks

Comment: it's hard to debug without any link to the website or working fiddle. Could you provide something?

Comment: Hello, here is the site: http://www.studiocaillouette.com/studio2/